# Valgrind debug logs for linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, valgrind

Goal:

1. Hi, I am new to valgrind and I need to run the valgrind on our existing code to check the memory leaks if any.

Result and problem:

1. I have one daemon running in backend which invoke multiple processes and which will never stop and scan the files. I have run the valgrind command on main daemon.
2. In another terminal I have test one scenario to get the logs and now I try to stop the valgrind by pressing ctrl+c and it will stop and give me the result of memory leak.
3. When I try to stop the valgrind/daemon by sending signal to daemon it will stop but not give me the proper logs.

Below is the example:
Press ctrl+c

```
==47030==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==47030==    by 0x6A1765D: IsSymbolicLink(char const*, stat, char*) (misc.cpp:352)
==47030==    by 0x6A28DCF: HandleEvents(int, Filter&) (rtsysitf.cpp:3639)
==47030==    by 0x6A25A63: ProcessMessage(void*, unsigned long const*) (rtsysitf.cpp:169)
==47030==    by 0x6A05AD5: CEventThreadpool::eventsDispatchThreadProc(void*) (EventsThreadpool.cpp:547)
==47030==    by 0x5BA46DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==47030==    by 0x5EDDA3E: clone (clone.S:95)
```

**IsSymbolicLink is the function in which I have written a code of memory leak for testing purpose and I got that in debug log when pressing ctrl+c**

**Also here I got 1000+ memory leaks in report which is not valid because allocating memory in constructor and deallocate it in destructor and pressing ctrl+c will never reach to destructor.**

When stop the daemon by : ./opssvc -stop

```
==25622== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 24
==25622==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25622==    by 0x4016077: _dl_close_worker.part.0 (dl-close.c:395)
==25622==    by 0x4016AF9: _dl_close_worker (dl-close.c:125)
==25622==    by 0x4016AF9: _dl_close (dl-close.c:842)
==25622==    by 0x5F2351E: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==25622==    by 0x5F235AE: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)
==25622==    by 0x4E3D744: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:162)
==25622==    by 0x4E3D0B2: dlclose (dlclose.c:46)
==25622==    by 0x407FFF: main (opssvc.cpp:457)
==25622==
==25622== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 24
==25622==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25622==    by 0x400C437: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:163)
==25622==    by 0x40069C4: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:943)
==25622==    by 0x400904B: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2389)
==25622==    by 0x400E361: openaux (dl-deps.c:63)
==25622==    by 0x5F2351E: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==25622==    by 0x400E667: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:249)
==25622==    by 0x4014F98: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:278)
==25622==    by 0x5F2351E: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==25622==    by 0x4014819: _dl_open (dl-open.c:605)
==25622==    by 0x4E3CF95: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:66)
==25622==    by 0x5F2351E: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
```

**When I stop the program in this way, I didn't get the log for the IsSymbolicLink function and got logs only for Dynamic libraries**

I have run the below command to check the valgrind:

valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --show-leak-kinds=all --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --log-file="/tmp/valgrind_log.log" ./opssvc

Can someone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I have a non-answer answer. Since the program is written by yourself, you may add a proper handler for Ctrl-C(the signal SIGINT, maybe) and make your program shutdown normally.

Comment: It's not a good answer, but I handle this by adding a switch to allow the code to be run in daemon or non-daemon modes, and then test the non-daemon version.

Comment: You need a proper shutdown, if your code is doing a lot of stuff, try by doing smaller part, perhaps using some of your test to check leak on a small stack. First step can be only on definite  `--show-leak-kinds=definite`

Comment: Hi all, I have added the handling for SIGINT in my code, now the service gets stop but still I got the logs for dlclose only. also --show-leak-kinds=definite that flag will not work. as the output is showing for dlclose..

Comment: Assuming that your daemon mode forks, you might want to try ` --log-file="/tmp/valgrind_log_%p.log"` or something similar so that you get one log file for both parent and child. %p will be replaced by the PID.

Comment: Hi @PaulFloyd, The daemon created multiple processes and I have tried that %p and got logs for per process in different files ended with PID.
Now I got something that when I stop valgrind process I got debug logs for that daemon only(opssvc) and not for the processes or .so files which are called by main daemon.

Comment: @Suyog  add the option --trace-children=yes